# Process independent function to allocate hugepage

Tags: c, memory-management, huge-pages

I'm reading through `hugetlb.c`, and found `alloc_huge_page()` can allocate a huge page, but process dependent, which means its parameter `struct vm_area_struct *vma` is a virtual memory area per process. However, what I want is a process independent data structure, because I want to build file system in virtual memory space, and try to allocate 2MB block to my file system.

Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: Can you explain more what sort of code you are trying to write?  I guess this is in Linux?  Kernel-mode code or user-space?  Do you know about FUSE (Filesystem in USErspace)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use file mapped share memory : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

You can also use a library such as shmem, but I'm not sure it supports Win32/64

Comment: What I want is to allocate page in kernel space, not user space, so I cannot use library. I think alloc_huge_page() can, but it is process dependent. alloc_fresh_huge_page() is process independent, but it only allocates virtual memory space, not real physical page.